# Создать вещественные индексы для varchar полей (mysql, mariadb)

Tags: mysql, float, index, cast

Есть поле varchar(255)
В WHERE обычно ищем по нему так:

```
CONVERT(REPLACE(mycharvar, ',', '.'), DECIMAL(8,2)) >= 125
```

Данные хранятся произвольные, но часто искать приходится по диапазону, приводя поле к вещественным числам и используя >, BETWEEN

Можно ли создать вещественные индексы по строковому полю. В данный момент даже для таблиц около 200тыс строк это работает крайней медленно.

Спасибо!

Comment: Переместите вопрос в англоязычный чат

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, первый раз тут)

Comment: *Можно ли создать вещественные индексы по строковому полю.* Нет. Но можно создать вычисляемое поле (generated column) и индекс по нему.

Comment: А зачем **числа** хранятся в виде строк? да ещё и с кривым десятичным разделителем?

Comment: Там всё хранится вообще, в том числе и числа (свойства товаров). По генерированным полям - понял, спасибо, так и поступлю

Comment: solved, генерируемые поля и индексы по ним - бомба. Вместо 5 минут - миллисекунды теперь) Еще раз спасибо.